# How do I find the smallest integer of $n$ such that $\sigma(n) = 24$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How do I find the smallest integer such that $\sigma(n) = 24$?

My attempt :
I listed out all the number one by one until I have $n = 14$.
But can I get the smallest integer number of $n$ by using the theorem instead of by listing it out one by one.

Can anyone help me? Will appreciate it alot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts on the matter: I believe there is no general algorithm except trial and error.

By "formula" you probably mean $\sigma(n) = \prod_{p|n, p \text{ prime}}(1+p+p^2+\dots+p^k)$. This could help in some cases, in particular if $\sigma (n)$ has very few divisors:

Suppose we are to find the smallest $n$ such that $\sigma(n) = 124 = 2^2\times 31$.

The factors of $124$ and $1,2,4,31,62,124$, so the sum of prime powers must equal to one of them.

$2$ is never attained, so we do not need to consider $62$. By brute force:

\begin{align}
4 &=1+3\\31&=1+2+4+8+16\\31&=1+5+25
\end{align}

and $124$ is never attained. This shows that $n = 3\times 16$ or $n = 3 \times 25$, so the minimum $n$ is $48$.

However this does not help with $\sigma(n)=24$, since $24$ has too many divisors.

There are other properties of the sigma function that can narrow your search:

- $\sigma(p) = 1+p$ for prime $p$
- $\sigma(n)$ is odd iff $n$ is a square or twice a square
- A naive bound: $\sigma (n) \le n+T_{n/2}=n+\frac {(n/2)(n/2+1)}2=\frac18(n^2+10n)$

In this case, the first criteria eliminates $2,3,5,7,11,13$, and the second elminiates $4,8,9$, and so $6,10,12,14$ remains. The bound can only eliminate the cases $n \le 9$.

Also check out https://oeis.org/A051444: `Smallest k such that sigma(k) = n, or 0 if there is no such k`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could "filter" some "reasonable guesses" in the following sense:

if $n = p$ is prime then $24 = 1 + p$, so $p = 23$ (and this is of course the unique prime with this property).

What other possibilities are there? Well, you can look at semiprimes less than $24$. Notice that if $n = pq$ with $p, q$ primes (at first sight not necessarily distinct!) then

$$\sum_{d \mid n} d = 1 + p + q + pq = (p+1)(q+1).$$

Write $24 = (p+1)(q+1)$ and see if you can find primes $p, q$ for which this is true. You'll notice that $p \neq q$, as otherwise $23 = p(p+1)$. Now look at the divisors of $24$ and you'll have your answer.

Comment: If $p=q$, then $\sigma(n)=1+p+p^2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen woops! I‘ll revise this, it’s still possible to discard this case since $24 = 1 + p + p^2$ implies $23 =p(p+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look for methods to find minimal $n$ with $\sigma(n)=m$ for larger $m$, where the one-by-one method is certainly not good enough or often not even feasible.

Recall that for prime powers $n=p^k$, we have $$\sigma(p^k)=1+p+p^2+\cdots +p^k=\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}=\frac{pn-1}{p-1}=n+\frac{n-1}{p-1}.$$
Also,  $\sigma$ is multiplicative.
So we might first look for prime $p$ that divide $m-1$ and check if $\frac{(p-1)m}p$ is a power of $p$. This will let us determine the set
$$A(m):=\{\,n\mid \sigma(n)=m\land n\text{ is a prime power}\,\}. $$
Do the same for all divisors $d$ of $m$, i.e., determine all $A(d)$ for $d\mid m$.
What we want is to find
$$ B(m):=\{\,n\mid \sigma(n)=m\,\}$$
(and ultimately its smallest element). To this end, note that
$$ B(m)=\bigcup_{d\mid m}\{\,xy\mid x\in B(d),y\in A(\tfrac md), \gcd(x,y)=1\,\},$$
which allows us to construct all $B(d)$ for $d\mid m$ recursively.